# Live results API for Tokyo Olympics 2020

Tags: data-request, sports

It is in a few years, but I am already creating an app for the Tokyo Olympics in 2020.
I would like my app to show **game results for every competition**/etc.

Is there an API that has pledged to deliver this information in near-real-time in 2020?

Data must be freely reusable.
Experience delivering similar results during previous Olympics greatly appreciated.